# Android bluetooth BLE notification speed

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a BLE device(sensor) and my android phone. I can connect to the BLE device just fine and receive notifications from it but the problem is that the time it takes to notify me about a new sensor value is too long. On the bluetooth docs it states that in typical applications it's like that but I was wondering if it's possible to lower the notification interval because I need the values quickly. Thanks

Comment: How are you getting the sensor value? Do you connect into device and doing a read request or only getting the data by advertising value? I think that the time of notification value provided by device depends itself.

Comment: Is this a programming question at all?

Comment: @Arubu, the characteristic is only notifiable but neither readable nor writeable. I connect to the device, set the characteristic notification to true to get the callback and write to the descriptor for that characteristic but as mentioned above, I get the notification fine but too slow. Is there a way as a client to configure the notification interval on the device?

Comment: @Meier, yeah it is a programming question. I want to know how to make the notification interval lower

Comment: @raiken77 Well, the notification time depends of the device. You can see if exist a charactertistic or descriptor to configure this time. Generally, a notification happens only when a new value change in device because of low power.

Comment: @Arubu thanks a lot for the answer, i'll try to find if such a characteristic exists on the device. Thanks again for the answer.

Comment: the problem statement is very vague. some unknown device. some unkown data. some unknown time, which is somehow to long. some unknown way to receive the values. some unknown programming language. no code how you receive the values.

Comment: @Meier sorry I thought the tags would describe what programming language I was using and the title help as well. So here's the detailed version. I have a speed and cadence sensor that I connect to using my phone over bluetooth then subscribe to a characteristic to get notifications. Then the device sends out an array of bytes containing some data that i'm not interested in and some that i'm interested in. The data arrives in interval of one second which is too slow for my application. I want to modify the device's settings to send it faster. For the code, I followed the bluetoothLEGATT example

Comment: Most of the S&C sensors I have seen only send the data once a second.  I believe the profile allows for quicker but it's up to the device what they do.  I have seen every 2 seconds so you could consider yourself lucky to be getting 1Hz.  What is your need for quicker?  ANT+ devices can go quicker (4Hz)  if it's quicker speed data you want.

Comment: Hey @Ifor sorry for the inactivity, I was away during the weekend. I need quicker speed data because I am sending this speed data to my desktop app via usb to do some data analysis. I looked at some ANT + devices would the magnetless speed sensor report values 4 times a second? I am asking because It costs and I want to be sure that it works as expected.

Comment: With ANT+ the transmition is a fixed 4 Hz rate.  If there has been a new wheel event with a magnet based system you get an update with the time for the last wheel revolution.  I don't have a new magnetless sensor to check.  There is a possibility that they hold off on the updates.  Getting the magnet timing good was easy with a read switch, from an accelerometer potentially with vibration there may well be a level of filtering and thus a significant delay on the data compared to the magnet based solutions.

Comment: @Ifor thanks for the explanation. I will get an appropriate device then.

Answer (score 1):

The notification interval is controlled by the device that sends the data.